# Contenteditable div with max length and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is the following task - I need to prevent input more than N symbols in contenteditable div with native JS / JQuery, i.e. user inputs 10 symbols and can't input more, only clear.

```
<div contenteditable="true" placeholder="Текст сообщения" class="editable ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"></div>
```

Comment: hi, i edited my answer so it would work with jquery 2.1 +

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you  The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/pj9wunf0/)

```js
$('#editcontent').on('keydown', function(event) {
  $('span').text('Characters entered:' + $(this).text().length);
  if ($(this).text().length === 10 && event.keyCode != 8) /*delete*/ {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
#editcontent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#editcontent:after {
  color: #999;
  content: 'Enter text';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editcontent" contenteditable="true"></div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: I don't use textarea, i use div with contenteditable property

Comment: not working with paste of content with over 10 char